# cakePHP tmp directory permissions

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

Is it OK to set the permission to `777` on the `/tmp` directory and its sub-directories? I am using CakePHP version 2.1.0.

When I try to set

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

It gives me Error:

> The requested address '/' was not found on this server.

But, with debug value of `1` or `2`, it works fine.

As I searched for this error I came up with results that it is because of tmp directory permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you set up your DATABASE_CONFIG is setup correctly (database.php)
2. Check that your tmp folder (and all of it’s sub folders) are writable (at least chmod 666 on Linux),
3. While you’re there delete all cache files from allof the tmp sub folders

After that, if you’re still having

> Error: The requested address "/" was not found on this server

then you’re likely to be missing a database table or an include file, so go into your core.php and set:

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've just installed cakePHP, no custom  controller, model or views yet (just cake's default files), database setup is ok, because with ('debug', 2), displays message: Your database configuration file is present. Cake is able to connect to the database. tmp dir permissions are 766, but as I try to set debug value to 0, it throws that error